# Is Big O time complexity of this sorting code n^2?

Tags: c, algorithm, big-o, bubble-sort

We know that bubble sort of array has time complexity of O(n^2).

I thought of using bubble sort to sort a singly linked-list.

Below is my C code. (`head` of list is passed by refernce to `headRef`). It does sort correctly, but my problem  is I find the concept of time-complexity a bit confusing, so although I think my below code also has complexity of O(n^2), I am not sure.

```
void sortNodes(struct node **headRef)
{
    struct node *head;
    int i, j, k;
    struct node *node_Pointer;
    struct node *node_Pointer_Left, *node_Pointer_Left_Left, *hold;
    printf("\nSorting started !\n--------------------\n");

    for (i=1; i<N; i++)
    {
            head = *headRef;
            node_Pointer = head;
            for(j=1;j<N;j++)
            {
                    {
                            // Making node_Pointer point to the jth node.
                            // Making node_Pointer_Left point to (j-1)th node.
                            // Making node_Pointer_Left_Left point to (j-2)th node. 
                            if (j > 1)
                                    node_Pointer_Left_Left = node_Pointer_Left;
                            node_Pointer_Left = node_Pointer;
                            node_Pointer = node_Pointer->next;
                    }

                    if ( node_Pointer->data < node_Pointer_Left->data )
                    {
                            //Below  part sorts by changing pointers.
                            //If you want to sort by swapping data, please comment below part.
                            //and uncomment the bottom part.
                            struct node *old_J_next = node_Pointer->next;
                            node_Pointer->next = node_Pointer_Left;
                            node_Pointer_Left->next = old_J_next;
                            if (j ==1)
                                    *headRef  = node_Pointer;
                              else
                                    node_Pointer_Left_Left->next = node_Pointer;

                            hold = node_Pointer;
                            node_Pointer = node_Pointer_Left;
                            node_Pointer_Left = hold;

                            //Below commented part sorts by changing (swapping) the data.
                            /*{
                                    int temp = node_Pointer->data;
                                    node_Pointer->data = node_Pointer_Left->data;
                                    node_Pointer_Left->data = temp;
                            }*/
                    }
            }
    }
    printf("sorting finished !\n");

}
```

Please confirm if the times complexity of above code is O(N^2).

My analysis: Outer for loop executes N-1 times and for each iteration of outer for loop, inner for loop executes N-1 times.And, for each iteration of inner for loop, there are some 'constant' number of statements which are executed. So total execution (approximate) = (N-1) * ((N-1)*constant) which will be of the order N^2.

Sadly, I am not confident that my analysis is correct, so I am posting it here. Would really thank if you told if it is right or wrong.

Comment: your analysis is correct

Comment: ^Thank you for conforming.

Comment: You could always test it with random lists of varying size and determine it empirically.

Comment: I concur with Lashane. Btw, its also not a bubble-sort as the comment indicates. A bubble-sort has an early exit clause to stop if any scan of adjacent elements in the remaining to-be-sorted segment yields no swaps. It is the attribute of the algorithm that provides best-case performance of O(N) on an already-sorted sequence.

Comment: I am just wondering, why is this question getting a downvote ? I have put quite some effort to write this question. Also I tried to write the question clearly (so that someone who reads this question will understand what i am trying to ask). Also i think this question is useful. This website says to downvote if a question lacks research effort, is not clear or useful. I think the question is clear and useful. However I am not sure about the "research" part, but I am quite sure that I put some "effort" to analyse the question myself before posting it here. I dont need upvote but why downvote ?

Comment: I haven't heard that a bubblesort should have an early exit clause as @WhozCraig says, but I heard of a different optimization: After the first run, you always have the maximum element at its position, so there's no need to touch that again. That mean that the inner loop would only do `N-i` iterations, making it still O(n^2). Also, you can reduce the number of comparisons to 3/4. Still, this is flogging a dead horse, as bubblesort has very low significance in practice.

Comment: @chris: Random inputs are unlikely be helpful for finding big O. There are plenty of problems where typical run time is fast but big O is bad.

Comment: An example of using a pointer-to-pointer enumeration strategy with swap detection [**can be seen here**](http://ideone.com/WrJgTE). I warn you, pointer-to-pointer work can get... convoluted, but the output should demonstrate where things are finally cut off once the remaining segment is known to be sorted due to no swaps. It should also be apparent that if even *one* element that belongs at or near *either* end of the list is at or near the *opposite* end, O(N^2) becomes unavoidable. Swap detection for early exit is a futile endeavor if that happens (and it happens often).

Answer (score 1):

Your analysis is spot on. O(n^2) it is.